# Android crash on boot - MediaButtonReceiver may not be null

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue in my Unity app where the Android build crashes on boot on a device running Android 4.3
The app loads a native plugin I wrote for playing music in the background while the app is suspended. It's using the Android MediaBrowser APIs and as such I'm using the "Compat" versions so continue support for previous versions of Android.

```
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): Unity version     : 5.6.1f1
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): Device model      : samsung GT-I9300
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): Device fingerprint: samsung/m0xx/m0:4.3/JSS15J/I9300XXUGMK6:user/release-keys
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.help.stressfree.mediabrowser.MusicService: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MediaButtonReceiver component may not be null.
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2697)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:159)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1404)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MediaButtonReceiver component may not be null.
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$MediaSessionImplBase.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:1054)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:176)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:118)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at com.help.stressfree.mediabrowser.MusicService.onCreate(MusicService.java:169)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2687)
06-07 09:59:37.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1748):     ... 10 more
```

My overriden Unity activity has this in onCreate

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // call UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Instance = this;

        LogHelper.d(TAG, "ThriveUnityPlayerActivity.onCreate");

        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicPlayerActivity.class);
        //startActivity(intent);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
```

And my MusicService class has the following onCreate function

```
@Override
     public void onCreate() {
         super.onCreate();
         LogHelper.d(TAG, "onCreate");

         //mPlayingQueue = new ArrayList<>();
         //mMusicProvider = new MusicProvider();
         //mPackageValidator = new PackageValidator(this);

         mMyServiceHandler = new Handler()
         {
             //here we will receive messages from activity(using sendMessage() from activity)
             public void handleMessage(Message msg)
             {
                 LogHelper.i(TAG,"handleMessage(Message msg)" );
                 switch(msg.what)
                 {
                     case 0:
                         PlayTrackByName((String) msg.obj);

                         break;

                     default:
                         break;
                 }
             }
         };

         // Start a new MediaSession
         mSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "MusicService");
         setSessionToken(mSession.getSessionToken());
         mSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCallback());
         mSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
             MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

         mPlayback = new Playback(this/*, mMusicProvider*/);
         mPlayback.setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_NONE);
         mPlayback.setCallback(this);
         mPlayback.start();

         Context context = getApplicationContext();
         Intent intent = new Intent(context, MusicPlayerActivity.class);
         PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 99 /*request code*/,
                 intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         mSession.setSessionActivity(pi);

         Bundle extras = new Bundle();
         //CarHelper.setSlotReservationFlags(extras, true, true, true);
         mSession.setExtras(extras);

         updatePlaybackState(null);

         mMediaNotificationManager = new MediaNotificationManager(this);
     }
```

Has anyone any idea what the crash means and how I would go about fixing it?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with some of my users. There's a possibility that the device they are using is unable to get the broadcast receiver component for media button action registered in the manifest. The device that have this issue for my users in ALCATEL ONETOUCH Flash Plus: version 4.4.4

Comment: The device in my case is a Galaxy S3

Comment: hey are you able to solve this problem can you share the ans is possible

Comment: Not had a chance to get back to this problem yet but I will.

Comment: @Zul same here. Any help?

Answer (score 22):

Try adding a media button receiver in manifest under the activity that controls the media I experienced this running 4.4, but not on higher versions.

```
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and read up;   [Media Button Receiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver.html)

Comment: In fact, this is required for pre-lollipop. Android team put together a good sample media player app which has [this code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/mobile/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L159).

Comment: If using AndroidX, class is `androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver`. More info here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver

Comment: @ThadeusAjayi , do you think we should use this `android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat` library while developing using androidx?

Comment: @juztcode I guess not. AndroidX would obviously have a different support library for mediasession

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue because of my mistaken.I defined two MEDIA_BUTTON action in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<receiver android:name="android.support.v4.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

So I delete one of them and error dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

**Update AndroidX**

```
<receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver" >
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```